# How to convert Spark map type into struct?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, dictionary, struct

Consider the code:

```
.withColumn("my_column",
    aggregate(
      col("input_column"),
      map(),
      (acc, c) => map_concat(acc, map(col("name"), col("other"))))))
```

This creates `my_column` with type `map<string, strcut<...>>`. Is there a way to make it `struct<string, struct<...>>`?

P.S. similar question - [How to convert array of struct into struct of struct in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769069/how-convert-array-of-struct-into-struct-in-spark)

Comment: AFAIK, and as I already mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771716/1386551), you'll need to collect all possible keys of the map column `my_column` in order to create the new struct. You can't use struct field aliases from column values in Spark.

Comment: The provided code does not seem correct - `c` is not used

Answer (score 0):

The following converts map to struct (map keys become struct fields).

```scala
val json_col = to_json($"col_map")
val json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select(json_col).as[String]).schema
val df2 = df.select(from_json(json_col, json_schema).alias("col_struct"))
```

In your case, it could look like this:

```scala
case class Strct(struct_name: String, struct_key: String)
val df = Seq(
    Map("x" -> Strct("x", "val1"), "y" -> Strct("y", "val2"))
).toDF("map_of_structs") 

df.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- map_of_structs: map (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- key: string
//  |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- struct_name: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)

val json_col = to_json($"map_of_structs")
val json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select(json_col).as[String]).schema
val df2 = df.select(from_json(json_col, json_schema).alias("struct_of_structs"))

df2.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- struct_of_structs: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- x: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- struct_name: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- y: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- struct_key: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- struct_name: string (nullable = true)
```